# Package java.util.regex supports which standards

Tags: java, regex, posix, posix-ere

I wanted to know java supports which standards for regular expression. By the word standards i mean does it support IEEE POSIX BRE, ERE, and SRE.

Can anyone give any idea.

Thanks in advance for the reply.

Comment: The [official tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/) says the syntax is similar to Perl's. So whatever that uses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This document](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) from Oracle contains extensive information regarding supported regex constructs in Java SE 7, although it does not mention what kind of standards are supported:

> **Comparison to Perl 5**
>
> The Pattern engine performs traditional NFA-based matching with
>   ordered alternation as occurs in Perl 5.
>
> Perl constructs not supported by this class:
>
> - Predefined character classes (Unicode character)
>
>   - `\h` A horizontal whitespace
>   - `\H` A non horizontal whitespace
>   - `\v` A vertical whitespace
>   - `\V` A non vertical whitespace
>   - `\R` Any Unicode linebreak sequence `\u000D\u000A|[\u000A\u000B\u000C\u000D\u0085\u2028\u2029]`
>   - `\X` Match Unicode extended grapheme cluster
> - The backreference constructs, `\g{n}` for the nthcapturing group and \g{name} for named-capturing group.
> - The named character construct, `\N{name}` for a Unicode character by its name.
> - The conditional constructs `(?(condition)X)` and `(?(condition)X|Y)`,
> - The embedded code constructs `(?{code})` and `(??{code})`,
> - The embedded comment syntax `(?#comment)`, and
> - The preprocessing operations `\l`, `\u`, `\L`, and `\U`.
>
> Constructs supported by this class but not by Perl:
>
> - Character-class union and intersection as described [above](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#cc).
>
> Notable differences from Perl:
>
> - In Perl, `\1` through `\9` are always interpreted as back references; a backslash-escaped number greater than 9 is treated as a
>     back reference if at least that many subexpressions exist, otherwise
>     it is interpreted, if possible, as an octal escape. In this class
>     octal escapes must always begin with a zero. In this class, `\1`
>     through `\9` are always interpreted as back references, and a larger
>     number is accepted as a back reference if at least that many
>     subexpressions exist at that point in the regular expression,
>     otherwise the parser will drop digits until the number is smaller or
>     equal to the existing number of groups or it is one digit.
> - Perl uses the `g` flag to request a match that resumes where the last match left off. This functionality is provided implicitly by the
>     `Matcher` class: Repeated invocations of the find method will resume
>     where the last match left off, unless the matcher is reset.
> - In Perl, embedded flags at the top level of an expression affect the whole expression. In this class, embedded flags always take effect at
>     the point at which they appear, whether they are at the top level or
>     within a group; in the latter case, flags are restored at the end of
>     the group just as in Perl.

Comment: [How to Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer): _A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there . Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline._